# how do i load test aws appsync?

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, loadrunner, aws-appsync

I am attempting to use Load runner to simulate 10k clients all subscribed to AWS Appsync.

My understanding is that it uses MQTT over Websockets.
I haven't been able to find documentation on how to achieve this with load runner.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (12.63) LoadRunner supports only MQTT over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

See VUGEN, advanced topics, creating virtual users in Visual Studio.   Use the published appsync C#, C++, VB interfaces.

An eclipse path exits as well if you are so inclined

Should AWS Appsync fail to meet your requirements, how will you post a defect to Amazon?  Do you have a strict SLA from Amazon on response times?